# FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING option not working for for Items files in Scrapyd - Python Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy, scrapyd

I am scraping Chinese website.

I have

`FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'`

in `settings.py` file.

If I run my scraper via

`scrapy crawl myscraper -o output.json`

Then my output file shows correct Chinese.

But if I start my scraper via `Scrapyd` then the Items created in `http://my-website:6800/jobs` are not encoded and not correct.

Why `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'` not working with Scrapyd?

Then I set `FEED_URI='files/output.json'` and then ran scraper via Scrapyd.

Now the output file at `FEED_URI='files/output.json'` is in correct format/encoding.

What could go wrong?

Comment: `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` comes with version 1.2.0 ([in this specific commit](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/33a39b368ffab6641997e7611d588487176716de)). Which version of Scrapy is being used within your Scrapyd environment?

Comment: @starrify `Scrapy 1.3.3` and `twistd (the Twisted daemon) 16.4.1`

Answer (score 1):

For now I haven't seen anything that Scrapyd might have done wrong with `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING`: it should have respected (to be precise, *untouched*) that setting.

> But if I start my scraper via Scrapyd then the Items created in http://my-website:6800/jobs are not encoded and not correct.

Did you just viewed the items in a browser window, or downloaded the full content on your local disk and viewed it using a UTF-8-supported approach?
Scrapyd's webservice does not specify an encoding when serving items ([code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/891b50c50377f1049a8eb4c4ec8ce70e3eacf987/scrapyd/website.py#L29)), which might lead to mis-interpreting. But the generated item files on the server ([sample path](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/891b50c50377f1049a8eb4c4ec8ce70e3eacf987/scrapyd/website.py#L150)) shall be okay. Can you verify that?

Comment: You are right, I was viewing it from browser, I downloaded it and it looks fine... Ok but its JSONLines... ... another thing I want is to beautify JSON to make it readable ...

Comment: @Umair I personally strongly recommend the JSON-lines format over JSON for storing scraping results, as a large JSON object is rather memory-unfriendly. Regarding readability, there're quite several tools for that. You may try [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), e.g. `cat results.jl | jq`.